# How to get the data property assertion value using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege4

I tried to make the below ontology. I want the data property assertion value using SPARQL.

[image]

I tried to make the query:

```
prefix ab:<http://www.semanticweb.org/bhuiyanh/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-38#>

SELECT ?AV ?lane
WHERE {
  ?AV ab:Driving ab:N_Time_1.
  ab:N_Time_1 ab:Driving ?lane.
}
```

I want the result like this:

```
AV  Lane
AV1  1
```

Comment: The property is called `lane`, so it should be `SELECT ?AV ?lane WHERE { ?AV ab:Driving ab:N_Time_1. ab:N_Time_1 ab:lane ?lane. }`

Comment: @AKSW Your comment is good. Please could you put it in an answer so the code can be properly formatted in an easy-to-read manner?

Comment: @AKSW.Thanks. It works now. But the lane result comes "1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>. Actually I want that the result will show only 1. Is it possible through SPARQL query?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so here's what could work.

Try casting the lane variable as an integer, because literals of the form  `"1"^^xsd:integer` are often written as `1`

```
prefix ab:<http://www.semanticweb.org/bhuiyanh/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-38#>
SELECT ?AV ?lane WHERE 
{ ?AV ab:Driving ab:N_Time_1. 
 ab:N_Time_1 ab:lane ?_lane. 
 bind( xsd:integer(?_lane) as ?lane )
}
```

OR try the string function:

```
SELECT ?AV ?lane WHERE 
{ ?AV ab:Driving ab:N_Time_1. 
 ab:N_Time_1 ab:lane ?_lane. 
 bind( str(?_lane) as ?lane )
}
```